# Get Max Date from Linq

Tags: linq

I wrote following query

```
var vehicleQuery = VehicleRepository.Where(o => o.IsActive && o.IsVisible);

var tempdate = vehicleQuery
    .Select(x => x.Images
        .Where(y => y.IsActive && y.IsVisible)
        .Max(u => u.CreationDate)
    );
```

How i get the Max CreationDate from Images entity?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany`;

```
var tempdate = vehicleQuery
    .SelectMany(x => x.Images
                      .Where(i => i.IsActive && i.IsVisible)
                      .Select(i => i.CreationDate))
    .Max();
```

**Edit**

> Error got := "The cast to value type 'System.DateTime' failed because
>   the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic
>   parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Maybe `CreationDate` is a nullable type and you have to check that:

```
var tempdate = vehicleQuery
    .SelectMany(x => x.Images
                      .Where(i => i.IsActive && i.IsVisible && i.CreationDate.HasValue)
                      .Select(i => i.CreationDate))
    .Max();
```

Comment: Error got  := "The cast to value type 'System.DateTime' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Comment: @ujjaval: Maybe CreationDate is a nullable type, edited my answer.

Comment: I have tried but still same i have public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a single max date, you'll need to use `SelectMany` to flatten the vehicles' images into a single sequence:

```
vehicleQuery.SelectMany(v => v.Images).Where(img => img.IsActive && img.IsVisible).Max(img => img.CreationDate);
```

Comment: I have faced the error :- " Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. "